# JavaFX renders the trailing spaces of TextFlow before its non-space charactes in case of RTL orientation

Tags: java, kotlin, javafx, right-to-left

I want to show some RTL texts, e.g. Farsi or Arabic, in a JavaFX application. I've written the following code that convert desired texts to TextFlow and add them to a VBox with `RIGHT_TO_LEFT` node orientation.
But if a text ends with spaces, JavaFX renders these spaces at the begging of the text rather than the end of it.

Let's take a look at my simple example:

```kotlin
class JavaFXBidiText : Application() {
    override fun start(stage: Stage) {
        val font = Font("Tahoma", 40.0)

        val vbox = VBox().apply {
            nodeOrientation = NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT
            spacing = 10.0
        }

        listOf(
            "\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645",
            "\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645            ",
            "\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645            \u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645",
        )
            .map { Text(it).apply { this.font = font }.apply { isUnderline = true } }
            .map { TextFlow(it) }
            .forEach { vbox.children.add(it) }


        val scene = Scene(vbox, 500.0, 200.0)
        stage.scene = scene
        stage.show()
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Application.launch(JavaFXBidiText::class.java, *args)
}
```

As it is shown in the following figure, the first and third texts are rendered correctly but the second is not.

[image: result]

How can I show these texts correctly?

Note that I am using JavaFX version 18.0.1 on jdk 17.

Comment: I can’t seem to reproduce this in Linux;  the text renders correctly, with the trailing spaces appearing to the left of the word on the second line.  I will try it in Windows as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behavior in Windows 10, either.  On what operating system are you seeing this behavior?

Comment: @VGR I appreciate your time. I'm om MacOS.

Comment: @VGR You are right. I tested my snippet in Linux. It was ok.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the Mac version of JavaFX.  Perhaps adding directional override characters might serve as a workaround?